# How to change $'s color in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

I'd like to change the `$`'s color in PHP Storm, I can't find any configure options in Preferences.

I've already tried to change the options in `Preference > Editor > Colors & Fonts`.

Comment: AFAIK that's not possible: the `$` is part of the variable itself, so it's colored in the same color as variable (depends on type: just variable, static field (e.g. `SomeClass::$shared`), instance variable (e.g. `private $my;`), function parameter, variable variable (e.g. `$$abc`)) -- all of them can have separate colors (in v9; in v8 some of these used the same color).

Comment: Thanks a lot .  I know that's impossible (based on v9). Just want to find out if there is a plugin or hack way could make it.